# relation between gaussian mixture models and maximum likelihood

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I need some help understanding the relation between the maximum likelihood and Gaussian mixture models. I have seen that there is a relationship between the Expectation Maximization algorithms and these two terms, but I could not understand quite well the relation. Could some please give me an example of how are these two terms related or different?